# Нужно установить div = ширине контента, используя flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

возникла проблема, div занимает всю ширину ( 6 класс ) предоставленную родительским div, а мне нужна ширина по контенту

```css
.wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 170px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 50px;
}

.button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #644499;
  text-align: center;
  width: 170px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.graybutton {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  text-align: center;
  width: 170px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.smallicon {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.info {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="info" style="margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px">Неизвестная ширина</div>
    <div class="smallicon">Неизвестная ширина</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="graybutton" style="margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px">
      Выход
    </div>
    <div class="button" style="margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px">
      Изменить EMail
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      Изменить пароль
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: я не понимаю что значит ширина по контенту. Для меня ширина по контенту это ширина родительского контейнера

Comment: У вас `.wrapper1` занимает 300px, вы для него написали `min-width: 300px`, что не так?

Comment: Там, где у меня написано "6 класс". Мне нужно чтобы прямоугольник в котором содержится эта запись увеличивался, зависимо от ширины самой записи, а у меня он шире необходимого: расползается на всю ширину большего wrapper1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте классу `.wrapper1` свойство `{align-items:flex-start;}`